# How to set Content-Type header charset in OpenRasta

Tags: .net, rest, http-headers, openrasta

When I return my object as JSON via JsonDataContractCodec OpenRasta sets Content-Type header to

> application/json

but ignores charset part of content type.

When I use Chrome it sends GET request with folowing header:

> Accept-Charset:windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

and all my utf-8 encoded json objects goes wrong.

I tried to override OperationResult with no luck. OpenRasta overwrites my header with codec's one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a way - inherit from JsonCoder and apply the `MediaTypeAttribute`:

```
[MediaType("application/json; charset=utf8")]
public class JsonWithEncoding:JsonDataContractCodec
{

}
```

And register handler with:

```
ResourceSpace.Has
  .ResourcesOfType<IEnumerable<ProfileResource>>()
  .AtUri("/profiles")
  .HandledBy<ProfileHandler>()
  .TranscodedBy<JsonWithEncoding>();
```

But this way is very static:(

Comment: you can also override the codec registration using .ForMediaType, that'll add the correct entry and ignore the attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Already founded it. But what to do if I want override it in OperationResult or it is wrong decision?

Comment: It should be a codec responsibility, not an OperationResult one, mostly because you should not have UI decisions happening in handlers. I'd think that you probably would want to change the codec to use your own json one that takes into account the accept-charset. Alternatively, you can create a new contirbutor that selects the correct encoding and for example prepares a TextWriter with the correct encoding by consumption for your codecs (so you don't replicate the code).